# Add an image gallery to a custom post type?

Tags: plugin-development, attachments, gallery

I am pulling data from an external web service into a custom post type. This data includes images. How can I create an image gallery, add some existing attachments to it, and associate it with a post?

What I was hoping to find is something like a `set_post_gallery` counterpart to the `get_post_gallery` function, but I can't find anything like it in the codex, on google, or in `wp-includes/media.php`.

This is how I set up the attachments:

```
$attachment = [
  'guid' => wp_upload_dir()[ 'url' ] . '/' . basename( $path ),
  'post_mime_type' => wp_check_filetype( basename( $path ), null )[ 'type' ],
  'post_title' => "$mlsNum $id",
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => 'inherit'
];

$attachmentId = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $path, $this->postId );

// Generate attachment metadata and create resized images.
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachmentId, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachmentId, $path ));
```

And this is how I am trying to retrieve the gallery for the theme:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
var_dump( $gallery );
var_dump( $post );
```

`$post` is defined, and `$gallery` is false. I was under the impression that `wp_insert_attachment` would create a gallery for the post and add the attachment to it, but apparently this is not the case. If it was, then that would cause other problems for me when I go to attach a PDF to the post.

Comment: Just had a look in the get_post_gallery function. It is regexing the post content for the gallery shortcode. That means if no shortcode present, no post gallery will be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just have raw image files, that you want to assign to a post, [`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) will do the job.

With attachments already present in your database you can use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to set the attachment's post_parent.
Like this:

```
wp_update_post( array(
    'ID' => $attachment_id,
    'post_parent' => $parent_post_id,
));
```

To recieve a post's attachments you can use `get_children`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_post_id,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);
$attachments = get_children( $args );
```

If you insist on using `get_post_gallery`– that will only return image attachments—you should add the `[gallery]` shortcode to your parent post content.

Comment: I also though `wp_insert_attachment` would add the attachment to the post's default gallery, creating it if necessary, but the codex makes no such promise (and the magic doesn't work for me). I wonder how the admin interface creates galleries...

Comment: There is no default gallery that I am aware of. A gallery is only identified by the image's IDs in the gallery shortcode. You could use the suggested `get_children()` to get all the attachments, or alternatively save the attachment IDs as meta for the parent post.

Comment: I have been using `get_children` and checking `mime_type` as a temporary solution, but I will switch to the `[gallery]` shorcode method so that the user can edit the gallery using the WP media manager on the post edit page. This will also make the plugin easier to integrate with other people's themes. I am not the first person to work on this site, and I probably won't be the last. It feels a little hackish to mess with the post content to manipulate the gallery, but it will do the job and there is no better way. Thanks Jörn!

Answer (score 1):

There's a great PHP solution here which will add the gallery editor to the custom post type editor - great, if like me, you are creating custom post types using PHP and importing data using WPAllImport. In this case, I want to ensure I use the default gallery so I can allow my clients to edit/add/delete imported images.

The code below adds the gallery editor to your custom post type editor interface:

https://gist.github.com/alexdunae/897503

Comment: Sigh, it's an iframe hack... but +1, it looks like it would work, and we have nothing better. It's because of stuff like this that I am now strongly favouring frameworks over CMSs.